# How to generalize a sequence of terms/patterns in this case

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, induction

$y_{0}=0$

$y_{1}=\frac{-1}{2}x^2$

$y_{2}=\frac{-1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{10}x^5$

$y_{3}=\frac{-1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{10}x^5- \frac{1}{80}x^8$

$y_{4}=\frac{-1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{10}x^5- \frac{1}{80}x^8- \frac{1}{880}x^{11}$

Now I am trying to figure out a general pattern. I can see that the powers follow an arithmetic sequence 3 is added each time. The denominator is the current power multiplied by its previous power. so for example $10 = 5 \times 2$ and $80 = 8 \times 5 \times 2$.

My problem is that I am not sure how to generalise this.

I am thinking $(\frac{1}{\prod^{n}_{k = 0} 3n-1}\times x^{3n-1}$). But not sure if this is correct? How can I prove by induction in this case? I have not done anything with the $\prod$ symbol before.

EDIT:

Thank you @mathlove for the detailed and thoughtful answer.

For the proving part, I forgot to write up the whole problem. But here it is: This problem about applying the methods of successive approximations ${φ0(x)=0, φ1(x), φ2(x), . . . , φn(x)}$ to the initial value problem.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -x + x^2 y,  \space y(0) = 0$$

where  $φ_{n+1}(x) = \int _{0} ^{x} f(s, φ_{n+1}(s)) ds$

Right now, I am having issues with verifying final form with induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am thinking $(\frac{1}{\prod^{n}_{k = 0} 3n-1}\times x^{3n-1}$).

You are almost there.

We can *guess* that for $n\ge 1$,
$$y_n=-\sum_{\color{red}k=1}^{n}x^{3\color{red}k-1}\prod_{m=1}^{\color{red}k}\frac{1}{3m-1}\tag1$$

For $n=5$, for example, $(1)$ gives
$$\begin{align}y_5&=-\sum_{k=1}^{5}x^{3k-1}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}
\\\\&=-\bigg(x^{2}\prod_{m=1}^{1}\frac{1}{3m-1}+x^{5}\prod_{m=1}^{2}\frac{1}{3m-1}+x^{8}\prod_{m=1}^{3}\frac{1}{3m-1}+x^{11}\prod_{m=1}^{4}\frac{1}{3m-1}+x^{14}\prod_{m=1}^{5}\frac{1}{3m-1}\bigg)
\\\\&=-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^5}{2\times 5}-\frac{x^8}{2\times 5\times 8}-\frac{x^{11}}{2\times 5\times 8\times 11}-\frac{x^{14}}{2\times 5\times 8\times 11\times 14}
\\\\&=-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^5}{10}-\frac{x^8}{80}-\frac{x^{11}}{880}-\frac{x^{14}}{12320}\end{align}$$

---

However, note that we cannot *prove* $(1)$ since from the given conditions, $y_n\ (n\ge 5)$ are not determined.

There are infinitely many examples which satisfy the given conditions.

For example, for $n\ge 1$,
$$y_n=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^{3k-1}}{f(k)}$$
satisfies the given conditions for any $a$ where
$$f(k)=ak^4+\bigg(\frac{334}{3}-10a\bigg)k^3+(35a-637)k^2+\bigg(\frac{3419}{3}-50a\bigg)k+24a-612$$

Note that for any $a$, we have
$$f(1)=2,f(2)=10,f(3)=80,f(4)=880,f(5)=24a+3078$$

---

**Added** :

Let us prove by induction that for $n\ge 1$, $$φ_n(x)=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{3k-1}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}\tag2$$

*Proof* :

For $n=1$, $(2)$ holds since
$$φ_1(x)=\int_0^x(-s)ds=-\frac 12x^2$$

Suppose that $(2)$ holds for $n$.

Then, we have
$$\begin{align}φ_{n+1}(x)&=\int_0^x\bigg(-s-s^2\sum_{k=1}^{n}s^{3k-1}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}\bigg)ds
\\\\&=\int_0^x\bigg(-s-\sum_{k=1}^{n}s^{3k+1}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}\bigg)ds
\\\\&=\bigg[-\frac 12s^2-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{s^{3k+2}}{3k+2}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}\bigg]_0^x
\\\\&=-\frac 12x^2-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^{3k+2}}{3k+2}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}
\\\\&=-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x^{3k-1}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}\end{align}$$

---

**Added 2** :

> How did you combine the $\frac{−1}{2}x^2$ into the summation symbol from $n$ to $n+1$ in the second and second to last line of your answer.

In the following, we prove that
$$-\frac 12x^2-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^{3k+2}}{3k+2}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}=-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x^{3k-1}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}\tag3$$

*Proof* :

Let $g(k):=\displaystyle\frac{x^{3k+2}}{3k+2}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}$ and $h(k):=x^{3k-1}\displaystyle\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}$.

Then, we have $$h(k+1)=g(k)\tag4$$ since
$$\begin{align}h(k+1)&=x^{3(k+1)-1}\prod_{m=1}^{\color{red}{k+1}}\frac{1}{3m-1}
\\\\&=x^{3k+2}\times \frac{1}{3(k+1)-1}\times\prod_{m=1}^{\color{red}k}\frac{1}{3m-1}
\\\\&=\frac{x^{3k+2}}{3k+2}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}
\\\\&=g(k)\end{align}$$

Also, we have
$$h(1)=\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\tag5$$

So, using $(4)(5)$, we can prove $(3)$ as follows :
$$\begin{align}&-\frac 12x^2-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^{3k+2}}{3k+2}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}
\\\\&=-h(1)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}g(k)
\\\\&=-h(1)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}h(k+1)
\\\\&=-h(1)-\bigg(h(2)+h(3)+\cdots +h(n+1)\bigg)
\\\\&=-\bigg(h(1)+h(2)+\cdots +h(n+1)\bigg)
\\\\&=-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}h(k)
\\\\&=-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x^{3k-1}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}\end{align}$$

Comment: mathlove, thank you for the working out. What you wrote made a lot sense! Right now, my issue is with the proof, especially with the symbols and the indexes. I have updated the question as I forgot to provide needed information for proving part.

Comment: @CountDOOKU : "my issue is with the proof, especially with the symbols and the indexes" I hope the following is helpful. Let $$f(k):=x^{3k-1}\displaystyle\prod_{m=1}^{k}\frac{1}{3m-1}$$ Then, $$φ_n(x)=-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)=-(f(1)+f(2)+\cdots +f(n))$$ where $$f(\color{red}1)=x^{3\times \color{red}1-1}\displaystyle\prod_{m=1}^{\color{red}1}\frac{1}{3m-1}=x^2\times \frac 1{3\times 1-1}=\frac{x^2}{2}$$ and $$f(\color{red}2)=x^{3\times\color{red}2-1}\displaystyle\prod_{m=1}^{\color{red}2}\frac{1}{3m-1}=x^5\times \frac{1}{3\times 1-1}\times\frac{1}{3\times 2-1}=\frac{x^5}{10}$$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much the answer and the comments really improved my understanding! However,  I have one more question. How did you combine the $\frac{-1}{2} x^2$ into the summation symbol from $n$ to $n+1$ in the second and second to last line of your answer.

Comment: Thank you mathlove for the guidance. This really helps!

Comment: @CountDOOKU : You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You’re thinking is correct.  All the $\prod$ symbol means is successive multiplication.  You’ve used that symbol implicitly without realizing many times before.  For example $x^n = \prod_{k = 1}^n x$ or $n! = \prod_{k = 1}^n k$. It is the same as a $\sum$, but for multiplication instead of addition.

But yes, from those patterns it seems to be exactly what you said you start with 0 then subtract $\frac{x^2}{2}$ then every successive term you subtract by adding 3 to the power of $x$ and multiplying the new power of $x$ to the previous denominator and that is your last part of your next iteration.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind also talk about the mathematical induction

Comment: Well, from my knowledge you wouldn’t really need induction because there isn’t really anything concrete or known about the sequence to use induction on.  Induction says that given one representation can I prove that there is another representation, but in this case technically you don’t have a representation yet because you don’t have a formula for them, so if someone was sneaky they could say the pattern changes after the 10th iteration.  The sequence isn’t recursive so you don’t need induction to show the closed form, you only have some of the sequence and it can be continued in any way.